# Find all extensions in a directory and order them alphabetically

Tags: python

I've got a homework which I am unable to solve :(

I have to use `os` and `os.path`.

1. I have to write a program which asks you for a directory but if you don't input anything the directory is current working directory, then it prints all file's extensions ordered alphabetically.

   The program should work like that:

   Directory:  `/Users/Andrew/Desktop`

   ```
   .ai
   .docx
   .jpg
   .png
   .py
   .rar
   .zip
   ```
2. I have to write a program which again asks you for a directory but if you don't input anything the directory is current working directory, then it prints all file's extensions ordered alphabetically but this time it should draw a line for every filetype and list the files with appropriate extension.

   Directory:  `/Users/Andrew/Desktop`

   ```
   .ai
   ----------
   cat.ai

   .docx
   ----------
   Job application.docx

   .png
   ----------
   Screen Shot1.png
   Untitled-1.png

   .py
   ----------
   1.py
   2.py
   4.py
   5.py
   6.py

   .xls
   ----------
   PlanB.xls
   Tommorow.xls
   ```

Your help would be appreciated.

This is my attempt at solving first problem:

```
import os

directory=input("Directory:")

if directory:
    files=os.listdir(directory)
else:
    files=os.listdir(os.getcwd())


for filetypes in files:
    print(os.path.splitext(filetypes)[1])
```

I finally did the first assignment, but I can't solve the second one. I'd really need help.

Thank you

Comment: Help us help you by posting what you have tried so we can guide you along; especially as this is homework. If we just gave you the solution, you won't understand much. What specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am going to vote to close this as too localized. The artificial restrictions of a homework question make this a one-off, and it's not going to be helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing this site with `DoMyHomwork.com`.   Please ask _specific_ questions relating to things to noted or didn't understand while `EFFECTIVELY trying to perform the task yourself`.

Comment: I edited it...I've been trying to solve this all day, but I guess I'm just stupid.

Comment: You are on the right track: so far your program can get an enumeration of all the file names and get the extension part of the name. Do note that a simple enumeration will likely produce duplicates (when the same extension is use a few times in the directory).  Now you need to store a single instance of each extension into a _container_ of sort.  In class you probably worked with lists, dictionaries and such; use one of these container classes you have studied.  Then sorting the list and printing out its content should be child's play.

Comment: You're not stupid. You just haven't learned how to think about these problems the right way yet. The difficulty we are having is that *for an already-skilled programmer* it's a very simple problem, so it's hard to answer the question without just telling you how to do it, but then you won't learn anything.  You should bring this question to your instructor; they know how to help without ruining your chances of learning anything.

Comment: Zack is right! It is a matter of learning how to "go about" this kind of problem (along with becoming more and more fluent in a particular language).  Python can be particularly tricky as a beginner's language because it allows expressing relatively complicated instructions in a very compact and "cryptic" fashion.  As you get more familiar with programming concepts, you'll love this feature of Python, but very early on, it is typically better to write your programs in multiple steps, leaving the "one liners" for when you are more fluent with the language.

Comment: Hi, could you guys please help me with the second one?

Answer (score 2):

To sort the file extensions, you need to add them to a list and then sort the list using `sorted()`.

To skip folders, you need to check for files in the for loop that goes through the file listing. You can use [`isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) for that.